# Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery. I get this error when I try to do this

Tags: sql

```
 SELECT
     SUM(CEILING(COUNT(m1.ReportId) / @limitvalue))  
 FROM
     mytable2 m2
 INNER JOIN
     mytable1 m1 ON m1.ReportId = m2.Id 
 WHERE 
     m1.Createdby = 3 
     AND m1.ReportId = 1115
```

Assume `@limitvalue` is 3.

Thank you in advance for the help provided

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use GROUP BY statement

Comment: The aiming result is one row length, group by will result in multiple rows returned!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can't use two aggregation functions (i.e. `Sum` and `Count`) in same selecte statement, you can split the query into 2, and `Sum` the output of the `Count` subquery

```
SELECT 
    SUM(sub.res)
FROM
    (SELECT 
        CEILING(COUNT(m1.ReportId) / @limitvalue) as res
    FROM
        mytable2 m2
    INNER JOIN mytable1 m1 ON m1.ReportId = m2.Id
    WHERE
        m1.Createdby = 3 AND m1.ReportId = 1115) AS sub;
```